# submiting a form by pressing an enter key

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wicket, wicket-1.5

I want to submit a form by pressing enter key. Wicket allows to do that till any button is attached to form and is visible.
Is there any way in wicket freamwork to submit a form by simple pressing an enter key?

enter works:

```
Form<?> searchForm = new Form<Void>("searchForm");
add(searchForm);
searchForm.add(button);
```

enter doesn't work:

```
Form<?> searchForm = new Form<Void>("searchForm");
add(searchForm);
searchForm.add(button);
button.setVisible(false);
```

In both cases button is a simple AjaxButton.

Answer (score 7):

Hide your button in the HTML with:
`style="visibility:hidden;"`

and then do this in the Java code:
`searchForm.setDefaultButton(button);`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a button (making the button invisible means it will not be rendered in the markup) then pressing enter on a text field can not submit the form. Either make it visible (obviously) or use some javascript to perform the submit on enter.

Example with JQuery:

```
$(submitOnEnter);
function submitOnEnter () {
    $("body").on("keydown", "mytextfield-selector", function(event){
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("myform-selector").submit();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: IT wasn't about jQuery. It was about Wicket freamwork which is a very streange tool for me :/